# Claculating direct mapped cache

Tags: caching

I'm just trying to solve this problem. Maybe you can help me.

```
_________________________________________________
|15|14|13|12|11|10|9 |8 |7 |6 |5 |4 |3 |2 |1 |0 |
|Tag        |Index.           |Word Off|Byte Offs
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
```

Tag= 4Bits

Index= 6Bits

Word Offset= 3Bits

Byte Offset= 3Bits

Totaly= 16Bits

For this I have the following tasks:

a) What is the data word width in bytes and bits? **I think 16Bits(2 Byte)**

b) What is the number of lines in the cache? **I think this is 2^index bits, so the result should be 64 cache-line**

c) How large is each cache line in bytes? **This should be 2^offsetbits, so I get 1 Byte (8Bit) as result.**

d) Which byte amount of pure data (without tags and flags) can the cache store?**Here I have calculated 2^Tagbits, and as a result 8 Byte received.**

e)What is the total size of the cache in bytes including one valid bit (per line) and the TAG bits?**each cache-line is 1 byte (8bit) in size, there are 64 cache-lines in total, 1 valid bit is added to each cache-line and 4 tag bits. So I have 13 * 64 = 832 bits = 104 bytes**

I'm not sure this is all right. Maybe you can help me.

Thank you already

salute

tobmes